# laravel 5.5 - wildcard subdomain not working

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

I am upload my laravel app in the `Apache` shared hosting server and everything setup fine. I have CNAME record set up `*` subdomain and point it to the `public_html/`. then I set this code in my `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($subdomain) {
        Route::get('/profiles/sub/{subdomain}', 'ProfilesController@subDomain');
    });
});
```

which `ProfilesController@subDomain` is a function to process the parameter `subdomain` from the `URL`. But the result keep sending me to the main landing page. I notice there is this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed

which I am not sure if it is something to do with any part.

How can I resolve this?

**Update01**

Following Ben's comment, I `force SSL` with the `.htaccess` below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>
```

It will force `http` to `https`. But whenever I test subdomain like `xxx.example.com`, Chrome will give a privacy error message, then change it back to:
[image]

and new error message:

> An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.

Just a reminder, I am trying to solve the wildcard subdomain issue here. If all this `SSL` is not the real reason, we can ignore that.

Comment: does your server has `SSL` certificate?

Comment: yes. I can use `http://` and 'https://'. both will point to the same page.

Comment: so your certificate is valid? Maybe you should force ssl...

Comment: @BenDubuisson What do you mean?

Comment: if you open that page through https in your browser, (Chrome), does it have a green lock on the side of it?

Comment: I mean forcing SSL, so that at the server level, any request that comes through http (80) gets redirect to https (443). It's a common practice. eg https://www.sslshopper.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html

Comment: @BenDubuisson Please see **Update01**.

Comment: @sooon ok, your certificate is not valid. But then again it might not solve your main problem, I was just trying to fix the error you posted. Does that error still show?

Comment: yeah actually I don't think your JS error has anything to do with it...

Comment: can you try
   `Route::domain('{subdomain}.example.com')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', function ($subdomain) {
    return $subdomain;
        });
    });`
to see if it even hits it?

Comment: I tried that. see my code above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165010/discussion-between-ben-dubuisson-and-sooon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.example.com')->group(function () { 
    Route::get('/', 'ProfilesController@subDomain'); 
});
```

and in `ProfilesController`:

```
public function subdomain($subdomain) {
//do something
}
```

AND as discussed, the order of routes is important, so if you have a route declared for `'/'` before this logic, it will always hit it first.